# При загрузке изображения из сети получаю NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android

Хочу отобразить изображение с сайта в `ImageView`. Нашел такой код в видеоуроке, но он не работает - компилятор выдает предупреждение об ошибке на строке `connction.connect()` и затем в методе  `getBitmapfromURL()`. Подскажите пожалуйста где я допустил ошибку?

```
package com.csgobets.bets;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Bitmap image;
    ImageButton iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL();
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://daypic.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1031-900x562.jpg");
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            return image;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

лог:

```
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1155)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:236)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.csgobets.bets.MainActivity.getBitmapFromURL(MainActivity.java:43)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.csgobets.bets.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
05-09 16:49:49.548    5307-5307/com.csgobets.bets W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Приведите сообщение об ошибке прямо в вопросе, вместе с командой, которая использовалась для компиляции. И используйте это сообщение, чтобы сделать заголовок вопроса более информативным.

Comment: Этот код будет работать только на старых версиях адроида. На новых - нет (на 4 андроиде и старше - точно).
В новых версиях нужно через asyncTask или thread. В основном потоке (где работает UI) в сеть лезть нельзя!

Comment: используйте библиотеки Picasso или Universal Image Loader. не пишите свой "велосипед"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` вот твой ответ.
Нельзя работать с сетью в основном потоке.

Вот решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/2604639)

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RSSFeed> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected RSSFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url= new URL(urls[0]);
            SAXParserFactory factory =SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlreader=parser.getXMLReader();
            RssHandler theRSSHandler=new RssHandler();
            xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRSSHandler);
            InputSource is=new InputSource(url.openStream());
            xmlreader.parse(is);
            return theRSSHandler.getFeed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```